# Nodejs and SQL - Issue with inserting data to SQL using multiple select statements

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OUX6j.png)
While inserting the data in SQL database table user_recipe_consumption by using multiple select statements i am facing error as - throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
      ^
Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Mushroom pasta');' , '( select vegEmission from RecipeEmissions where RecipeName' at line 1

```
for (var dataVal = 0; dataVal < req.body.length; dataVal++) {
    var recipeInfo = req.body[dataVal].RecipeName;
    var deviceID = req.body[dataVal].deviceID;
    var totEmission = req.body[dataVal].totalEmission;
    var sql = "INSERT INTO user_recipe_consumption (deviceID, totalEmission, recipeID , vegEmission,date_of_entry) VALUES ('" + deviceID + "','" + totEmission + "', '( select RecipeID, from RecipeEmissions where RecipeName = ?);' , '( select vegEmission from RecipeEmissions where RecipeName = ? );' ,'" + now + "')";              
    con.query(sql, recipeInfo, function(err, result) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log("Number of records inserted: " + result.affectedRows);
        });
    }
```

Comment: Hi Nishtha, can you add to your question what you have tried so far to solve your problem? Have you tried running the query directly against your database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have too many semicolons in your SQL statement. You're also putting single-quotes around a subquery, which effectively turns it into a string literal. And you're using `NOW()` incorrectly. Try this:

```
var sql = "INSERT INTO user_recipe_consumption (deviceID, totalEmission, recipeID , vegEmission,date_of_entry) VALUES ('" + deviceID + "','" + totEmission + "', ( select RecipeID, from RecipeEmissions where RecipeName = ?) , ( select vegEmission from RecipeEmissions where RecipeName = ? ) , NOW())";
```

If you mean `now` to be a JS variable then you can revert that part of the query to what you had originally, but it's not clear what `now` is supposed to contain.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of SQL with var concated (and related problem with data type and SQL injection) you should use a query completely based on param binding (eg: named param). You should also use a insert select syntax instead of several select from the same table

```
"INSERT INTO user_recipe_consumption (deviceID, totalEmission, recipeID , vegEmission,date_of_entry) 
SELECT :deviceID, :totEmissino,  RecipeID, vegEmission, :date_of_entry 
FROM RecipeEmissions 
where RecipeName = :RecipeName;"
```

eg:

```
connection.execute(
    "INSERT INTO user_recipe_consumption (deviceID, totalEmission, recipeID , vegEmission,date_of_entry) 
    SELECT :deviceID, :totEmission ,  RecipeID, vegEmission, :date_of_entry 
    FROM RecipeEmissions 
    WHERE RecipeName = :RecipeName;",
    {deviceID: deviceID, totEmission: totEmission, date_of_entry:date_of_entry,RecipeName:RecipeName},
function(err, result)
.......
```

Comment: deviceID and totEmission doesn't belong to any table so i cannot use select :deviceID here. deviceID and totEmission fields are obtained from request body of post call. Rest of the fields are to be selected from table.

Comment: When you use  select :deviceID, :totEmission you are just assigning  to the named  var  :deviceID, :totEmission  the value you pas  as param with   {deviceID: deviceID, totEmission: totEmission ...  is as you are selecting  literal values